# Not able to get admin privileges. Error Domain=CFErrorDomainLaunchd Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CFErrorDomainLaunchd error 2.)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to get user permission in order uninstall an application. In order to get the rights. I am following this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) published by Apple.

The article is using this library

```
#include <ServiceManagement/ServiceManagement.h>
```

**What I am Doing?**
Github Project: [Here](https://github.com/bansalvks/MacPOCes/tree/master/UserAuth)

**Error**

> Error Domain=CFErrorDomainLaunchd Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (CFErrorDomainLaunchd error 2.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this problem when trying to use the SMJobBless example (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless), which is referenced in the article you mentioned.

In my case the reason was that the helper tool that was supposed to be installed by the SMJobBless() function was not located at the expected location (Contents/Library/LaunchServices within the application wrapper).

See the copy files build phase of the SMJobBless example.
Once I added a similar build phase to my project, I no longer got the CFErrorDomainLaunchd error 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, saved my day! Also, i would like to add. Daemon binary name should match "Label" value from *-Launchd.plist. /Library/PrivilegedHelpers contains some useful names :)

Comment: This answer did not helps me, privileged helper is located at the correct place, but still get the same error. I know it's related to updating the helper tool with a  new version when the current helper tool is still running. This can be solved by calling SMJobRemoved, but unfortunately this method was deprecated since mac os x 10.11.

Comment: @kato2 Long time since, but were you able to fix your helper updating error? I'm seeing the same thing.